# Nifi for parsing HL7

Tags: hdfs, hl7, apache-nifi

I am trying to parse **HL7** files stored in **HDFS** using **NIFI** but i am not finding any examples or the proper way to achieve this. Please help.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/20318/visualize-patients-complaints-to-their-doctors-usi.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pull the files out of HDFS using ListHDFS + FetchHDFS, then use the ExtractHL7Attributes processor to get information out of the HL7 file, then from there use other processors to do whatever you want with the results.

All of the available processors along with documentation are here:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html

Comment: Thanks for your response !